# Syntax error or access violation when using STRPOS with semicolon character

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a table `table1` with the following data

```
+----------------+
|     model      |
+----------------+
| a45/ a45m;aa45 |
| b34/b34m       |
| c23;c23m/ cc23 |
+----------------+
```

I'm trying to clean up the `model` field with certain rules, such as

1. grab all characters before the first `;`
2. from `1`, grab all character before the first `/`

So I do the following in `netezza` for step 1

```
SELECT
    SUBSTR(model, 1, STRPOS(model, ';')-1) AS model_clean
FROM table1
;
```

This throws error `ERROR [42000] Syntax error or access violation`. Any ideas why this is happening, does the character `;` need to be escaped ?

One thing to note is that When I look for the `space` character as following, there is no error.

```
SELECT
    SUBSTR(model, 1, STRPOS(model, ' ')-1) AS model_clean
FROM table1
;
```

Also is there a way to get step 2 also done in this same `select` statement ?

**Expected output**

```
+----------------+
|  model_clean   |
+----------------+
| a45            |
| b34            |
| c23            |
+----------------+
```

Comment: Please do not tag your question with `postgresql` if you are using Netezza. Those are two different database products

Comment: The SQL you give in your post references a column "model" but does not reference a table.  If run as you present it here it would return this error: "ERROR:  Attribute 'MODEL' not found."  The error you give in your post claims to be a syntax error, which likely doesn't have anything to do with STRPOS.  For syntax errors it's best to post the entirely of your SQL.

Comment: Also, it would be helpful to include a sample of expected output.

Comment: @ScottMcG - added table reference and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because not all columns have semicolons, so `strpos()` returns 0.  You can fix this just by adding a semicolon:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(model, 1, STRPOS(model || ';', ';') - 1) AS model_clean
```

Comment: Tried this, however continue to get the error `ERROR [42000] Syntax error or access violation`

Comment: One thing that makes me think it is not only about some rows not having `;` , the statement `SELECT
    SUBSTR(model, 1, STRPOS(model, ' ')-1) AS model_clean
;` gets through without errors though not all rows have a whitespace

Comment: I think Gordon’s solution is very close to a working one. Try concat’ing a ; to all occurrences of ‘model’ more specifically the one before the very first comma: SELECT SUBSTR(model||’;’, 1, STRPOS(model||’;’, ';')-1) AS model_clean ;

Comment: @user3206440 . . . Could one of the values start with the semicolon?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - after spending some time, the issue was nailed down to the SQL parser of the interface that I use to connect with Netezza. It apparently considers `;` as end of statement. The work around currently is to use `chr(59)` instead of `;`.

Answer (score 0):

Your query fails when you try to do substring with an invalid position, the result of strpos wich didn't found the semicolon.

You can use case statement to avoid calculate invalid position

Here are an example of SQLServer syntaxe ( `charindex` and `strpos` have reversed parameter order, up to you to reduce the query) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/55a6e/25

```
WITH step1
     AS ( SELECT CASE
                   WHEN CHARINDEX(';', model) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(model, 1, CHARINDEX(';', model) - 1)
                   ELSE model
                 END AS model
            FROM table1 ),
     step2
     AS ( SELECT CASE
                   WHEN CHARINDEX('/', model) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(model, 1, CHARINDEX('/', model) - 1)
                   ELSE model
                 END AS model
            FROM step1 )
SELECT *
  FROM step2;
```

Comment: Kobi: your answer wil not work on netezza, since it’s a MPP database execution, so all the ‘fragments’ of your CASE will be evaluated for all rows, even those with an empty string... Gordon Linoffs solution is closer to working in my experience.